# Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type - Block only working on development environment

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We have a setup of 3 environments which are currently exact copies, and managed using GIT.
The environments:

- Develop (development)
- Acceptance (testing)
- Master (live)

I developed a custom module for a block that displays some products. The module is active on all 3 environments, and shows up in the list of modules via the admin.

To display the block I use an XML update on a CMS page, this page is exactly the same on all 3 environments too.
Somehow the block is displayed on `Develop` but not on `Acceptance` or `Master`, while `Develop` does not log any errors or exceptions on the other environments I do get the following exception:

```
2018-09-18T12:12:40+00:00 ERR (3): 
Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type: BeterSport_CustomUpsellList_Block_Customupselllist in /data/web/staging/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block ty...')
#1 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('BeterSport_Cust...', Array)
#2 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('customupselllis...', 'customupselllis...')
#3 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('customupselllis...', 'customupselllis...')
#4 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '231')
#9 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/PageController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '231')
#10 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_PageController->viewAction()
#11 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#12 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /data/web/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /data/web/staging/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /data/web/staging/index.php(80): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

What could be the cause for the block to not work, and why does it work on `Develop`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type` is caused by a CASE-sensitivity difference between my Development (Windows) and Testing/Live (Linux) environment.

**Solution:**

Change the block's class name to the correct Magento naming convention, see below for the code change.

**From:**

```
class Vendor_Module_Block_BlockNameHere extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
```

**To:**

```
class Vendor_Module_Block_Blocknamehere extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
```

> Change `BlockNameHere` to `Blocknamehere`, starting with a capital only.

Answer (score 0):

Are the branches deployed in different environments?
If this is the case, the issue could be related to environment and its data base and not only to git branches. 
Are you displaying your block inside a CMS Block like: `{{block type=rss/order_new}}`?
Then you must give permission inside Magento panel to this block type.

Here you can follow the right steps for this:
https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/permissions-content.html

---

If the issue happens in the same data base and you are showing your block directly 
 by XML then you should flush cache after changing the branch and check if module is enabled by code (try a hello world controller).

Hope it helps you.
Regards.

Comment: I would appreciate if you read my full post. Your answer doesn't help me.

Comment: Hi @J.Meijer
If Magento is retrieving you a Invalid block message is because the module is not enabled or the block has no permission. If the code of your module is the same then is something related to enviroment: database, code differences between branches or anything like this.

Comment: As said in my post, the module is active on all 3 environments, as said I checked this in my admin, also no exceptions would be logged if the script wasn't loaded.
My block is loaded by XML, no permissions are required for this (I added them anyways).
My environments are all 3 equal, except for small changes made to products or cms pages on live.

Comment: Hi, please, could you show me the XML layout where you are inserting the block? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cesar, maybe you can read my post again. You are asking me questions that are clearly mentioned in my post.

Comment: I have read your post several times and it doesn't have enought info to get through the error because the "Invalid block type" is a very common message error in Magento. 
 I'm missing possible module conflicts between branches, code differences and database differences. So if the code of the module is the same only could something related to the environment. 
I'm sorry but I can't help you.